# Cannot Delete My Folder

Tags: delete, secure-erase

I can't delete a folder that is taking over 9GB. It's a timeshift backup folder but I can't delete it. Which commands should I use for it?

I tried `sudo rm -rf /timeshift` to delete it but it did not work.

Comment: See which process has it open with `sudo lsof /timeshift`.

Comment: Can you also share the terminal output after your sudo `rm -rf` ?. As the @wltinator suggested checking the process that is using your folder, also you might want to restart just in case of any process could use your folder or related files.

You can also try with different run levels like `sudo init 3`. Then you can try it with `sudo rm -rf`. But I don't think that is the problem.